# C compiler issue, multiple path definitions/links

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, mingw

I'm working with the NXP LPCopen C library. I'm using Eclipse Mars and MinGW/gcc. I'm encountering an issue in Eclipse where a specific typedef is producing an error:

> "conflicting types for 'LPC_GPIO_T'"

Based on the files I'm using (and confirmed with a CTRL+H search), `LPC_GPIO_T` is only being used in 3 places:

1) In gpio_002.h, where the struct is defined

```
typedef struct {       /* GPIO_PORT Structure */
    __IO uint32_t DIR;     /* Offset 0x0000: GPIO Port Direction control register */ 
    uint32_t RESERVED0[3];
    __IO uint32_t MASK;    /* Offset 0x0010: GPIO Mask register */
    __IO uint32_t PIN;     /* Offset 0x0014: Pin value register using FIOMASK */
    __IO uint32_t SET;     /* Offset 0x0018: Output Set register using FIOMASK */
    __O uint32_t CLR;      /* Offset 0x001C: Output Clear register using FIOMASK */
} IP_GPIO_002_T;
```

2) In chip_lpc175x_6x.h, where the typedef is being declared

```
typedef IP_GPIO_002_T LPC_GPIO_T;
```

3) In gpio_17xx_40xx.h, where it is a parameter to a function

```
STATIC INLINE void Chip_GPIO_WritePortBit( LPC_GPIO_T *pGPIO, uint32_t port, uint8_t bit, bool setting) {

    IP_GPIO_WritePortBit((LPC_GPIO_T *) (LPC_GPIO + port), bit, setting);
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what the issue is to fix it. I'm happy to post any of the relevant files if it will help.

Comment: Build your source file with the `-E` flag to get preprocessed output. Then check the output to see the exact definitions in place.

Comment: Also, doesn't the compiler tell you where the conflicting types are? It should have a message like `<file_name>:<X>:<Y>: note: previous declaration of 'LPC_GPIO_T' was here`

Comment: you have a misunderstanding.   Your point `2` is just defining yet another typedef, not declaring any actual instance of that struct

Comment: in point `3`, where the parameter `LPC_GPIO_T *pGPIO` is being passed, the caller must have an instance of the struct,  something like: `LPC_GPIO_T *ptr;`  then some code filling in the fields of that struct, then `Chip_GPIO_WritePortBit( ptr, .... );`  where 'ptr' is a declared variable in the code that makes the call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the compiler did not directly tell me where the conflict was. Looking around through all the files I found my conflict. I posted this question when I thought there wasn't a conflict to find.